# JDK1.7 - retrieving enum constant with dots in their values

Tags: java, enums, jdk1.7

I'm using a thirdparty library which has an enum class which is as shown below:

```
public enum Version { 
VERSION_2_0("v2.0"), 
VERSION_2_1("v2.1"), 
VERSION_2_2("v2.2")

private final String urlElement;

  Version(String urlElement) {
    this.urlElement = urlElement;
  }

  public String getUrlElement() {
    return this.urlElement;
  }

  public boolean isUrlElementRequired() {
    return null != this.urlElement;
  }


}
```

I'm reading version from props file which i want to pass to this enum to get respective enum constant like this:

```
String str="v2.2"; //this i get from a props file    
System.out.println("version enum: "+Version.valueOf(str));
```

I'm getting  below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.pkg.Version.v2.2
```

It seems "v2.2" is not getting treated as single string. I tried couple of ways by escaping dot in the string, but none of them are working. I'm using JDK1.7. So anyone encountered this, please advise.

Comment: Show your full `enum` declaration. You will need to add a method to look up the `enum` constant using your value properties.

Comment: Hi, i've updated question with full enum class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add a method to look up the `enum` constant based on your value property. It could look something like this:

```
public enum Version {
    VERSION_2_0("v2.0"),
    VERSION_2_1("v2.1"),
    VERSION_2_2("v2.2");

    String value;

    Version(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static Version byValue(String value) {
        for (Version version : Version.values()) {
            if (version.value.equals(value)) {
                return version;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you can do the lookup as follows:

```
Version version = Version.byValue("v2.2");
```

If performance is important, you might want to add a map to avoid the iteration over the enum values and speed up the lookup.

**Update**

If the `enum` itself cannot be modified, you can implement the same mechanism in another class that you do have access to. In line with your updated code, it would look like this:

```
static Version byUrlElement(String urlElement) {
    for (Version version : Version.values()) {
        if (version.getUrlElement().equals(urlElement)) {
            return version;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or, if you want to further optimize with a map:

```
private static final Map<String, Version> VERSION_INDEX = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (Version version : Version.values()) {
        VERSION_INDEX.put(version.getUrlElement(), version);
    }
}
```

And then you can perform your lookups using the map:

```
Version version = VERSION_INDEX.get("v2.2");
```

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, its a class from from thirdparty library, which i can't modify. :)

Comment: @kaluva What methods does the enum expose?

Comment: If necessary you can implement The `byValue` method everywhere you want. There's no strict need to implement it in `Version`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, thanks for the update. Actually, I need to pass this  version while making http call in my code. So everytime evaluating like this seems performance bottleneck. I can consider map option as you suggested to avoid this performance hit. Just wanted to know, no other way to support this in java instead of iterating over enum constants?

Comment: @kaluva Since the strings you have do not match the enum names, the best you can do is a manual mapping to enum constants. There is a pattern which could allow to construct the enum name from the string by some string manipulation, but my guess is that a precomputed static map is faster than that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, for now i'm going with your approach. But i still want hear any other nice suggestions to achieve this without iterating enums. Anyways, thanks guys for the support.

Comment: @kaluva I've updated to include the approach with the lookup map. The enum will only need to be iterated once when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot update the Enum so write a program which return the Enum Name by value.

```
public static String getEnumNamebyValue(String str){
        for(Version v : Version.values()){
            if(v.getVersion().equals(str))
                return v.name();
        }
```

return null;
}